# How to project/unproject when in an openGL display list

Tags: opengl

I have openGL code that renders some objects and displays text labels for some of them. Displaying a label is done by projecting the appropriate vertex to the screen using gluProject, and then adding a small offset so the label is beside the vertex. This way each label is the same distance from its vertex on the screen.

I didn't originally use a display list for this (apart from the display lists for the glyphs), and it worked correctly (if somewhat slowly). Now I build a display list for the entire scene, and find that the labels are placed incorrectly.

It took me a while, but I think I have basically found the problem: gluProject takes as parameters the projection matrix, model-view matrix, and the viewport. I see no way to provide them other than calling glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, ...), etc. But glGet functions are "not allowed" in a display list, which - empirically - seems to mean that they don't cause an error, but rather execute immediately. So the matrix data being compiled into the display list is from list compilation time instead of list execution time (which is a problem because I need to precompile the list, not execute it immediately). At least this is my current theory.

1. Can anyone confirm or deny that this would cause the problem?
2. How does one solve this? I just want to do what gluProject does, but using the *list's* current matrices.

Note: I'm aware that various functions/approaches are deprecated in recent versions of openGL; please spare me answers along the lines of "you shouldn't be doing that" ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Think about it: `glGet…` places some data in your process memory, possibly on the stack. There is absolutely no way, how a display list could even reproduce the calculations performed on data, that is not even in its reach. Add to this, that GLU (note the U) functions are not part of OpenGL, hence don't make it to the display list. GLU functions also are not GPU accelerated, all the calculations happen on the CPU and due to the API design data transfer is rather inefficient.

Scrunities like those, which as you find out, make display lists rather impractical are among the reasons, why they have been stripped from later versions of OpenGL. Or in other words: Don't use them.

Instead use Vertex Buffer Object and Index Buffers. A labeling system like yours can be implemented using instancing, fed by a list of the target positions. If instancing is not available you need to supply redundant position attributes to the label's vertex attribute vector.

Anyway: In your case making proper use of shaders and VBOs will easily outperform any display list based solution (because you can't display list everything).

---

Rather odd, but working would be calls to glRasterPos, glBitmap (hence glutBitmap text calls) put in a display list, and the offset applied in the projection matrix before the actual projection mapping, i.e.

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECITON);
glLoadIdentity();
scene_projection();

draw_scene();

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECITON);
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(...); /* for the offset */
scene_projection();

draw_labels();
```

Though this is how I'd have done it 12 years ago. Definitely not today.

Comment: When I call, say, glRotate in a display list, a matrix multiplication is performed. So the display list, when executing, must somehow have access to the current projection / model-view matrices (or no?). Could one then not somehow do what glProject does (not necessarily call it directly, but apply the same calculations), multiplying with those matrices? That's what I meant by "using the list's current matrices". Or am I misunderstanding something (which is quite possible)?